Unable to Validate Leave Due to Inactive Analytic Account odoo15
I’m currently working with Odoo, and I'm quite new to the platform. I encountered an issue while trying to validate a leave request for one of my employees. The system returned the following error message:

"You cannot add timesheets to a project or task linked to an inactive
analytic account."

After some investigation, I realized that this error is related to the association of the leave request with a project or task that uses a specific analytic account. In Odoo, if this account is inactive, the system blocks certain actions, such as adding timesheets or validating leave requests.
I have checked the related project and task settings and found that an inactive analytic account is likely causing this problem. However, I'm not entirely sure how to proceed from here. I would appreciate guidance on how to reactivate the analytic account or adjust the project/task settings to resolve this issue.
Since I’m new to Odoo, any detailed steps or best practices related to managing analytic accounts and their connections to leave requests would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you for your help!

Is your question related to how to use or is it an issue wirth programming?

Anything  can help me to solve the problem
